# Android/iOs: Decode polyline string

Tags: android, ios, mapbox, polyline

I want to decode poly-line strings ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)) on Android and iOS.

Example:

```
    _p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@
```

I know there is the possibility to use the [google-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) but since I'm using Mapbox I don't want any Google dependencies in my project (furthermore, I'm not allowed to).

Does Map-box provide the same functionality for the mobile SDKs? I saw they have something for `JavaScript` but I would like to do it natively, to reduce the size of `JSON` responses from the server.

Or is my only option to implement my own decoding-algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapbox provides the same functionality as part of [Mapbox Android Services](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#mapbox_android_services). For example, you could do the following with no Google dependencies:

```
List<Position> path = PolylineUtils.decode(
  "_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@", Constants.GOOGLE_PRECISION);
```

Also, because the precision is configurable, you could also apply the same method to other encoded polylines, like those coming from OpenStreetMap.

For more examples, you can [check the tests](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/libjava/lib/src/test/java/com/mapbox/services/utils/PolylineUtilsTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<LatLng> decodePolyLines(String poly){
    int len = poly.length();
    int index = 0;
    List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < len){
        int b;
        int shift = 0;
        int result = 0;
        do{
            b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        }while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >>1));
        lng += dlng;

        decoded.add(new LatLng(
                lat / 100000d,
                lng / 100000d
        ));
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

You can use this function to decode the polyline and create a List of LatLng